# Rewriting my code as a Method, using C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, methods, parameter-passing

I am currently having trouble understanding Methods and how they work in C#. I currently have code written for a car cost calculator program I created, I want to rearrange or break my code down using methods. I am unsure how or where to begin doing so as it pertains to my program. Here is my code, clarification would be helpful! Thank you!

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //constants for the Zone entered by user
    const decimal ZoneCostN = 27;
    const decimal ZoneCostS = 36;
    const decimal ZoneCostE = 45;
    const decimal ZoneCostW = 54;

    private void CalcButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //set the variables
        decimal PackWeight = 0;
        decimal CostZone = 0;
        decimal CostWeight = 0;
        decimal ShippingTot = 0;
        decimal Net = 0;
        const decimal PerPound = 18;

        //parses the entry into the textboxes
        decimal.TryParse(WeightText.Text, out PackWeight); ;

        //algorithm for variables
        CostWeight = PackWeight * PerPound;
        Zonelbl.Text = "";
        CostZone = 0;

        //if else statement to get the zone cost
        {
            if (NorthButton.Checked)
            {
                CostZone = ZoneCostN;
            }
            else if (SouthButton.Checked)
            {
                CostZone = ZoneCostS;
            }
            else if (EastButton.Checked)
            {
                CostZone = ZoneCostE;
            }
            else if (WestButton.Checked)
            {
                CostZone = ZoneCostW;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Select a zone!");
            }
        }
        //algorithm to get total and net
        ShippingTot = CostZone + CostWeight;
        Net = ShippingTot / CostWeight;

        //if condition for CAPPED label
        if (ShippingTot >= 100)
        {
            CAPPEDlbl.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            CAPPEDlbl.Visible = false;
        }

        //output for all the data
        Zonelbl.Text = CostZone.ToString("c");
        Weightlbl.Text = CostWeight.ToString("c");
        Totallbl.Text = ShippingTot.ToString("c");
        Netlbl.Text = Net.ToString("c");
    }

    private void ClearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //clears the form
        Zonelbl.Text = "";
        Weightlbl.Text = "";
        Totallbl.Text = "";
        Netlbl.Text = "";
        WeightText.Text = "";
        CAPPEDlbl.Visible = false;
        WeightText.Focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: The Click event handlers are both examples of methods.

Comment: Reading this should be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/methods

Comment: @Handbag Crab Right, but that was created for me as an event when I created the "calculate" button. I guess for example. How would I put the first if/else statements into it's own method?

Comment: @elgonzo I have read through that, I guess maybe I'm not understanding how I could break down my code using a method. The concept seems straight forward, but I can't see how it would apply here.

Comment: A method can be used to encapsulate a block of code, which does some calculations or decisions and returns a value. For example, you could replace the `if` statement with: `decimal costZone = GetCostZone();`. Then you would put the `if` statements in your new method: `public decimal GetCostZone() { if (NorthButton.Checked) return ZoneCostN; if (SouthButton.Checked) return ZoneCostS; if (EastButton.Checked) return ZoneCostE; if (WestButton.Checked) return ZoneCostW; return 0; }` Then, back in your main method, you might do something like `if (CostZone == 0) MessageBox.Show("Select a zone!");`

Comment: If you can't see how you can break down your code in different methods then don't force yourself. I don't know and i might misunderstand what you want, but it feels like you insist on refactoring your code into multiple methods while lacking a clear motivation/reason (the "why") for doing so...

Comment: As a (very general) rule, usually the time to move some code into a separate method is when that block of code has a distinct purpose and you want to be able to re-use the same functionality again, but passing in different values as the input (e.g. some code to send an email, or do a particular piece of arithmetic, or display some data in a particular format). You can almost think of a method as being a miniature program in itself - designed to complete a specific job within the context of a bigger program. Thus bigger programs are made up of lots of these little re-usable building blocks.

Comment: Thank you for all your responses. It's easier for me to understand a new concept when I can relate it to a program I have already done. Or when it's put into layman terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, we create methods when we need to reuse a code. In your case, you should see which part of your code will be reused in the future. If it is a simple form you may don't need to change anything but imagine you want to use your clear functionality somewhere else, create a method and call it everywhere you need

```
        void clear()
    {
        Zonelbl.Text = "";
        Weightlbl.Text = "";
        Totallbl.Text = "";
        Netlbl.Text = "";
        WeightText.Text = "";
        CAPPEDlbl.Visible = false;
        WeightText.Focus();
    }


    private void ClearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    clear();
}
```

Now you can reuse clear() and in case you needed to change it you only need to change the method. It's the concept and you can apply it wherever you need.